# Smart distinct in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not very familiar with the functional Pandas but could not find a solution to this problem in the documentation.

I want to make DISCTINCT the table for ID, writing in the cell TRUE if this ID TRUTH ever met and FALSE otherwise.

Input:

```
            ID    VALUE
---------+-----+-------
 0           1     True
 1           1     True
 2           1    False
 3           1     True

 4           2     True
 5           2    False
 6           2    False
 7           2    False

 8           3    False
 9           3    False
10           3    False
11           3    False
```

Result:

```
            ID    VALUE
---------+-----+-------
 0           1     True
 1           2     True
 2           3    False
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) will return true if at least one element of the group is true. The `reset_index` then transforms `ID`, which is an index after `groupby`, back into a column.

```
df.groupby("ID").any().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   ID  VALUE
0   1   True
1   2   True
2   3  False
```